# Multipart requests error when installing Spring 3.1.2 war file to WebSphere 8.5 beta

Tags: spring, websphere, multipart

When trying to install a Spring 3.1.2 (servlet 3.0) WAR to WebSphere 8.5 beta using the Admin Console, I get the following error:

```
[2012/11/08 10:19:32:585 CAT] 00000021 srt E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest parseParameters SRVE0133E: An error occurred while parsing parameters. {0}
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: SRVE8020E: Servlet does not accept multipart requests
```

I have configured my DispatcherServlet to handle multipart requests (even though I don't need support for this, but WebSphere 8.x seems to require this, see JIRA below).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>10000000</max-file-size>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Unfortunately the Spring JIRA https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9191 simply implies that either this web.xml configuration or the Spring Java config annotation @MultipartConfig should work.

This problem does not occur on WebSphere 7 (servlet 2.5) or WebSphere 8.0 (servlet 3.0). I am able to use WebSphere 8, but any info on why it doesn't work in 8.5 beta would be good.

Comment: Facing same problem as mentioned in this question

Answer (score 0):

Check your schema version in `web.xml`, it should be at least 3.0

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd